# Why default constructor is not provided by compiler when class contains parametrized constructor defined by user?

Tags: java, default-constructor, parameterized-constructor

I am a newbie in java and was wondering "Why default constructor is not provided by compiler when class contains parametrized constructor defined by user?"

Comment: Why do you think it should?

Comment: Because that is how it is. And because ALWAYS having a default constructor is VERY bad practice because what values are all your fields supposed to have? `null`?

Comment: default constructors are only a convenience. You are better off giving fields a reasonable initial value if you can.

Comment: Next to the explanation which are already given. Maybe you're interested in lombok. Which can help to do some simplification writing POJOs and other classes with annotations.

https://projectlombok.org

Answer (score 5):

When an author decides to not provide any constructor, it is perfectly fine that the compiler adds that default constructor. *Obviously* the user doesn't care "how" objects of that class are created, he accepts that the "default" kicks in.

But as soon as the author writes down a constructor with parameters, it is also *obvious* that he assumes that one of his constructors gets used.

The straight forward reasoning: assume your class has multiple fields, and the user-written constructor initializes all of them. What should the compiler-generated default constructor do about these fields?! And as one of the comments pointed out: leaving them at `null` or maybe 0 isn't a good idea.